# How to loging to django with login form? With or without Ajax

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

**Problem:**
If user is loggedin, I want to show greet user else show the form
and when the valid data is submitted, log in the user and
show greet message.

I am trying to pass the data on submit and update the user status to login. I tried with and without ajax but with both ways I could not figure out solution. Could you please help me why its failing? And how I can solve this?

HTML Form:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h5 class="title billing-title  ls-10 pt-1 pb-3 mb-0">
            Welcome {{ user.username }}!
        </h5>
        {% else%}
        <div class="login-toggle">
            Returning customer? <a href="#"
                class="show-login font-weight-bold text-uppercase text-dark">Login</a>
        </div>
        <form class="login-content" name="ajaxLogin" method="POST" action="{% url 'ecommerce:ajaxlogin' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            
            <p>If you have shopped with us before, please enter your details below. 
                If you are a new customer, please proceed to the Billing section.</p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Username or email *</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-md" name="username" id="id_email"
                            required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password *</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-md" name="password" id="id_password"
                            required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" id="remember" name="remember">
                <label for="remember" class="mb-0 lh-2">Remember me</label>
                <a href="#" class="ml-3">Lost your password?</a>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-rounded btn-login" type="submit" >Login</button>
        </form>
        {% endif%}
```

Views.py :

```
def ajaxlogin(request):
    is_ajax = request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
    if is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
      username = request.POST['username']
      password = request.POST['password']
      user = authenticate(user=username, password=password)
      if User.is_active and not None :
            login(request)
      else:
            pass             
         
    return render('./ecommerce/checkout.html')
```

AJAX:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.login-content').on('submit', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();     
      var action_url = $(this).attr('action')
      
  
      $.ajax({
        url: action_url,
        type:"POST",                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        data: $('.login-content').serialize(),  
        headers: { "X-CSRFToken": $.cookie("csrftoken") },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("login Successful");
            
        },
        
        
    });
  });
  });
```

Comment: "Could you please help me why its failing" you need to help  us with that. Do the checklist: 1. Is your ajax function called? 2. is django accepting the request? 3. what does django send back? (use prints to see where its stuck). Somewhere in there you get an error. render('./ecommerce/checkout.html') seems wrong. In case of a success you want to send back a simple "logged in" or "wrong password or username" . Check your browser console and terminal log for more infos

Comment: I applied views as @user8193706 mentioned, I got following error: https://imgur.com/8KIIzW9

Comment: Inside network I can see this error :
https://imgur.com/XUdBsMn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django `authenticate` takes keyword arguments `username` and `password` for the default case with `request` as optional parameter.

In your `views.py` you pass `user` as parameter in authenticate change it to `username`.
The default `authentication` returns None if user is in-active so you don't have to check for `is_active` if you are using default authentication.

Change your `views.py` as

```
def ajaxlogin(request):
    is_ajax = request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
    if is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None :
            login(request, user)
        else:
            pass             
     
    return render('./ecommerce/checkout.html')
```

Also set `contentType` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or leave it at the default by omitting the `contentType` key.

Comment: How can I refresh page or content after login successful so that  Welcome {{ user.username }}! part will be published?

Comment: For page refresh use location.reload() inside ajax success